# How to push config file to new oryd/hydra docker image?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am using the oryd/hydra docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/oryd/hydra
in order to build a custom image with my own configuration.

I did create a custom directory:

```
mkdir sso-demo-hydra
cd sso-demo-hydra
```

then I create a Dockerfile using that syntax:

```
vi Dockerfile
```

the file content:

> $ cat Dockerfile
>
> FROM oryd/hydra:latest
>
> COPY .hydra /

when building the image I get no error:

> $ docker build -t sso-demo-hydra .
>
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.704kB
>
> Step 1/2 : FROM oryd/hydra:latest
>
> ---> 50f0a70dbda9
>
> Step 2/2 : COPY .hydra /
>
> ---> Using cache
>
> ---> 3539634979c0
>
> Successfully built 3539634979c0
>
> Successfully tagged sso-demo-hydra:latest
>
> SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.

And when I launch the application I get the following warning:

> sso-demo-hydra | Config file not found because "Config File ".hydra" Not Found in "[/]""

PS: there is a .hydra file in the context directory

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

See [github source code](https://github.com/ory/hydra/blob/master/cmd/root.go#L88) of this docker image, the related code is as next:

```
func initConfig() {
    if cfgFile != "" {
        // enable ability to specify config file via flag
        viper.SetConfigFile(cfgFile)
    } else {
        path := absPathify("$HOME")
        if _, err := os.Stat(filepath.Join(path, ".hydra.yml")); err != nil {
            _, _ = os.Create(filepath.Join(path, ".hydra.yml"))
        }

        viper.SetConfigType("yaml")
        viper.SetConfigName(".hydra") // name of config file (without extension)
        viper.AddConfigPath("$HOME")  // adding home directory as first search path
    }

    viper.SetDefault("LOG_LEVEL", "info")

    viper.SetEnvKeyReplacer(strings.NewReplacer(".", "_"))
    viper.AutomaticEnv() // read in environment variables that match

    // If a config file is found, read it in.
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(`Config file not found because "%s"`, err)
        fmt.Println("")
    }
}
```

From above, you can see in fact what it expected is `.hydra.yml`, not `.hydra`, `.hydra` just the one which remove extension:

> viper.SetConfigName(".hydra") // name of config file (without extension)

So the root cause is: its error indication not friendly which make you encountered problem, change to use `.hydra.yml` could make it ok.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs, anyway I've resolved this using environment variables. The configuration file is not the proper way to do it

Answer (score 0):

In this case I suggest you pass the configuration file (--config ) when starting the docker container. For example:

```sh
docker run -d \
  --name ory-hydra-example--hydra \
  --network hydraguide \
  -p 9000:4444 \
  -p 9001:4445 \
  -e SECRETS_SYSTEM=$SECRETS_SYSTEM \
  -e DSN=$DSN \
  -e URLS_SELF_ISSUER=http://127.0.0.1:9000 \
  -e URLS_CONSENT=http://127.0.0.1:9020/consent \
  -e URLS_LOGIN=http://127.0.0.1:9020/login \
  -v $(pwd)/hydra.yaml:/hydra.yaml \
  oryd/hydra:v1.8.5 serve all --config hydra.yaml --dangerous-force-http
```

This way you don't need to create your own dockerfile.